# Issues when follow xaml shell document to create a FlyoutHeader

Tags: forms, shell, xaml, mobile

today I met an issue for creating a flyoutheader: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout

The example doesn't show the steps on how to create the Flyoutheader contentview, but just the xaml content.
So I created a new folder 'Controls' in order to add the FlyoutHeader ContentView object. Then created a new contentview FlyoutHeader which name space is: ShellDemo.Controls.FlyoutHeader, it's a subclass of ContentView.
The content of it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ShellDemo.Controls.FlyoutHeader"
             HeightRequest="200">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Image Aspect="AspectFit"
               Source="xamarin_logo.png"
               Opacity="0.6" />
        <Label Text=""
               TextColor="White"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

But then in the AppShell.xaml when I tried to include it as the Shell.FlyoutHeader content, it has a blur red line error, said can't find the FlyoutHeader.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyyVw.png)
I have tried to restart VS for Mac and rebuild all and upgrade all to latest, all doesn't work.

But actually when you press the debug button, the application can be successfully run in the mobile simulator.

Then I suspect it's my namespace defined wrong from AppShell.xml file? Here is my AppShell.xml:
Please see what the issue is here, I also suspect it's a VS for Mac defect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShellDemo.Views"
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ShellDemo.Controls"
       Title="ShellDemo"
       x:Class="ShellDemo.AppShell"
       FlyoutIcon="icon_about.png"
       FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
       FlyoutWidth="200"
       FlyoutHeight="400">

<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <controls:FlyoutHeader /> <!-- This line report red blur line error -->
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>
...
```

Update:
Today I got a new update of VS for Mac and this issue was gone.

Comment: you must create custom FlyoutHeader content template

Answer (score 0):

Just create new ContentView named as FlyoutHeader and paste below code and you want to any custom control, you must create the control before using it.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Xaminals.Controls.FlyoutHeader"
         HeightRequest="200">
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
           Source="xamarinstore.jpg"
           Opacity="0.6" />
    <Label Text="Animals"
           TextColor="White"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added this control yesterday, thanks for your notice. This issue is resolved by today's new VS for Mac updates.